# How to fetch JSON data when the values are in below format?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

```
{"cities":[{"city":{"id":1,"name":"Bangalore","status":"Active"}},
{"city":{"id":2,"name":"Mysore","status":"Active"}},... ]}
```

The above is the JSON format and this is how I fetch from JSON as shown below,

```
$city=$data['cities'];
$citycount=count($city);
for($i=0;$i<$citycount;$i++)
{
  echo $data['cities'][$i]['city']['id'];
}
```

Now How to fetch JSON values when the format is like below

```
{"result":[["id","name","status"],[1,"Bangalore","Active"],[2,"Mysore","Active"],... ]}
```

I'm using core PHP to fetch data from JSON with the method `file_get_contents` and `json_decode`

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried to fetch values?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Ya but I'm trying for other format which I specified in above. Trying in different format.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas I'm trying to fetch values from new JSON format

Comment: json_decode will successfully decode it into a php object. Next you have add some checks for the first array because it has headers as well as data.. after that.. you need a loop for the rest of arrays to extract data.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas It has header but no data in first array. Data are in next array as shown in the SECOND  format.

Comment: if you look carefully, then the first array has as first element, an array with all the header items. and then the second, third, fourth elements are the values..

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this.

```
$result = json_decode($newjson);
$result = $result->result;
$data = [];
$headers= $result[0]; // get the first row.
foreach($result as $key => $row) {
   // ignore the headers row.
   if($key != 0) {
       array_push($data, [
          $headers[0] => $row[0],
          $headers[1] => $row[1],
          $headers[2] => $row[2]
       ]);
   }
}
```

To show these values in form elements like 'dropdown' use this.

```
<select name="somename">
   <?php foreach($data as $item) { ?>
      <option><?= $item['name'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It is showing invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

Comment: Yea.. Now it is displaying the values of JSON. But how to display it in text box or dropdown box.

Comment: $result = $result->result; are you sure you did this?

Comment: that is another concept for starters use 
<input type="text" value="<?= $data[0][1] ?>" >

Comment: Its working for single value.. How to do it for dynamic values? how to include it in `foreach`

Comment: could you please accept my answer as the correct one too?

Comment: @Mabashar Abbas . Another doubt... The above code is working fine till now only when there is one JSON fetching attempt  but how to do the same when there is more than one JSON fetching in `foreach`. Its not working when I implement two `foreach` in same php page.

Comment: You should post another question for that and if my answer solved your problem, then you should mark it as correct.

Comment: also check the tick option below the voting buttons. it will turn green.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$json = '{"result":[["id","name","status"],[1,"Bangalore","Active"],[2,"Mysore","Active"]]} ';
$result = json_decode($json,true);
$dataArray = [];
foreach($result['result'] as $key => $value) {

   if($key != 0) {
       array_push($dataArray, [
          $result['result'][0][0] => $value[0],
          $result['result'][0][1] => $value[1],
          $result['result'][0][2] => $value[2]
       ]);
   }
}
print_r($dataArray);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a more dynamic method, does not matter what headers you have it will combine automatically, but is very important that each row need to contain the same array length.

```
$data = '{"result":[["id","name","status"],[1,"Bangalore","Active"],[2,"Mysore","Active"]]}';

$_data = json_decode($data);
if(!empty($_data)){
    $i = 0; //I know that the first row is the header
    foreach($_data->result as $row){
        if($i++ == 0){
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $newData[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($newData);
}
```